# Making iPhone/iPad the master when syncing with iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, data-synchronization

I am syncing my iPhone with my Mac using iTunes. How do I make the iPhone have priority over the Mac? I mean, I want to copy what is on the iPhone to iTunes, deleting from iTunes what is not anymore on the iPhone.

I hate when I clean my phone, do a sync, just to have iTunes copy everything back, because iTunes database regarding to that phone is not the same.

iTunes gives what is on iTunes a priority and I want the reverse.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially - you don't.

iTunes is the master, the iDevice is the slave. That's the way the system is designed.

It works on the assumption that you will always have plenty of room on your Mac to store data that there is no room for on the phone, so you can add it back to the phone at any time in future.

I suppose it's legacy behaviour from before iCloud existed.

Answer (score 1):

Use iTunes in Microsoft Windows. It does the opposite of the Mac - iPhone relationship.  I wanted to "clean up" the playlists on my iPhone so I deleted all my playlists off my phone.  I also deleted all the songs--why iPhone doesn't have an option or prompt for this when deleting a playlist is beyond me.  Anyway, when I attached my iPhone to my Windows computer, iTunes started the automatic sync, and when it was done it deleted all the playlists that used to be on my iPhone even though those playlists were originally created in iTunes on my Windows computer.  It seems the Apple people cannot write a sync program to save their lives.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have any windows machine but thanks anyway.